# How to mock the entire axios object using sinon?

Tags: javascript, axios, sinon, stub, loopback4

I want to stub the entire axios object using sinon. My axios call is like

```js
const response = await axios({
      method,
      url,
      headers,
      data,
});
```

I have found out that if my call was like

```js
const response = await axios.get(url, data);
```

Then I could stub the function like

```js
sinon.stub(axios, "post").resolves(mockResponse);
```

But this is not working for the `axios()` call, but only for `axios.post()`.

Comment: This is what [moxios](https://github.com/axios/moxios) is for. Alternatively (and what I recommend), don't mock anything except for the response using [MSW](https://mswjs.io/), the fact the request is being made through axios is an implementation detail